# How to show a graph daily, weekly, and monthly?

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

I have a csv file for my data and I want it to show depending on what the users want, I have a button for daily, weekly, and monthly. But I do not know how to format it to only show daily, weekly or monthly.

Here is my code for parsing the date

```
d3.csv("/dates_name_value.csv",function(d){
    return { date : d3.timeParse("%Y-%m-%d")(d.date), value : d.value, name: d.name }
  }).then(
```

It only shows this by default:
[image: pic of graph]